# Xcode, getting unused Variable message

Tags: xcode4, compiler-warnings

Am new to programming. Got a little problem with Xcode. I get this message "UNUSED VARIABLE"
for a small basic variable input.

```
int x;
```

Answer (score 0):

The message is telling you what it's telling you.  You've declared a variable but aren't using it.  It's not an error, just a warning.

Comment: I it is just high lighted in yellow colour and at the end of the line giving a message UNUSED VARIABLE nothing more than that. When I run the entire program me I get out put and also there no errors. Is that ok If i get that message "unused variable"?

Comment: It's fine.  What Xcode is saying is, "You've declared this variable, it's taking up memory, but you're not using it."